# Calling unity in terminal breaks unity in X session

Tags: unity

I'm totally new at Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and it was working perfectly. I went to the terminal and typed `unity`, the screen went wild for a little while and then my desktop was the classic desktop which I hate. Now, how can I go back to unity?... I restarted and watched at the options in the bottom of the screen when I select my user name but there is non that says unity on it, I chose `Ubuntu`, since the others include Classic in its "description". I also went to the terminal, and typed `unity` again to see if I could revert it, and the same, but in the output, it was this:

```
unity-panel-service: proceso no encontrado //PROCESS NOT FOUND, i use Spanish
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
//THE NEXT ROW REPEATES MANY, MANY TIMES, WITH MANY 0 IN THE LAST CHARACTER
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap is missing
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Software rendering detected
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
```

... Unity was just working so great =(...

Comment: So, if you are already run Unity and you run again `unity`, then Unity gets messed up? If so, file a bug report ASAP on launchpad.net

Comment: @user4124 Can you explain to me what that command does? `unity`

Comment: Please try restart your system

Comment: What driver are you using? It seems to me like your drivers are messed up some how, since compiz is falling back to software rendering and unable to start.

Comment: @Roger: `unity` runs the unity window manager; however, it's already running because you logged into the "Ubuntu" desktop. It looks like you're having problems because you tried to run unity when it was already running.

Comment: Running `unity` just restarts unity.

Comment: maybe log-in option "Ubuntu" should better be named "Ubuntu (Unity 3D)"?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "I went to the terminal", do you mean a virtual terminal inside of windows? or a real text terminal, like Ctrl-Alt-F1 or the like?

If you did the latter, then the normal way to get back to the existing windows desktop is to do Alt-F7 or F8 or which ever one X is running on.  Notice the control key is not needed when returning to X.

NOTE: I have never used or seen Ubuntu 11.x, still using 9.04 myself.

Comment: Just an FYI: 9.04 reached End of Life in the past year, you should consider updating to the LTS to recieve long-term support. Also, wherever they type the command is generally irrelevant - if the thing can't run from the tty, the system should state as such: "No X Server available" (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

@Terry seems to be right.

calling `unity` in a Ctrl-Alt-F1 tty gives the following output, and breaks the running unity (2d) session in Ctrl-Alt-F7:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

user@host:~$ unity &
[1] 3137
user@host:~$ WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
unity-panel-service: no process found

(process:3139): GLib-WARNING **: In call to g_spawn_sync(), exit status of a child process was requested but SIGCHLD action was set to SIG_IGN and ECHILD was received by waitpid(), so exit status can't be returned. This is a bug in the program calling g_spawn_sync(); either don't request the exit status, or don't set the SIGCHLD action.
GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; the most common cause is a missing or misconfigured D-Bus session bus daemon. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Abnormal program termination spawning command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=e1415082f4c221cc22bbf8954b115eb2 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': )
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
...
... repeated 80 times
...
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing commands options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing wobbly options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing scale options...done
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: Unity accessibility initialization
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: Shows on edge: 1

(<unknown>:3139): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:3139): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Screen geometry changed:
  Monitor 0(primary)
   0x0x1920x1200

unity-panel-service: no process found
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: PanelController:: Added Panel for Monitor 0
Initializing unityshell options...done
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Applications
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Commands
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Files & Folders
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: /com/canonical/unity/applicationsplace
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: /com/canonical/unity/filesplace
Couldn't find a perfect decorator match; trying all decorators
Starting unity-window-decorator
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: Setting to primary screen rect: x=0 y=0 w=1920 h=1200
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: Lost the name com.canonical.Unity.Launcher on the session bus

** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libapplication.so
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libsoundmenu.so
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libmessaging.so
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libdatetime.so
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libme.so
** (<unknown>:3139): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libsession.so
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're missing the --replace option - when you log in, press Alt-F2, then type "unity --replace" without the quotes in the box and press enter. If the box doesn't come up, try doing it from the classic session.

Comment: You don't really need the --replace.